# The operation can’t be completed because the item is in use

Tags: macos, mojave, filesystem, trash

I can not empty trash folder, getting message "The operation can’t be completed because the item “7” is in use."
Tried

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash/*
```

Getting message that directory is not empty:

[image]

But looks like there is nothing:

[image]

Tried everything posted about this bug, even restarted under Command+R mode, first aid for disk done, nothing found, system consistency off, etc.

So, any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you attempting to remove your `~/.Trash` directory?

Comment: Sorry, typo, /.Trash/* of course. Fixed

Comment: Have you tried emptying it via the GUI?

Comment: Using "Empty trash" button? Sure I did

Comment: You say you've restarted with command+r, have you tried deleting the contents of .Trash from there?